# Can writes to a datagram socket ever raise SIGPIPE?

Tags: c, sockets, posix, datagram, sigpipe

I'm working with some code that needs to be safe against killing the caller due to `SIGPIPE`, but the only socket writes it's performing are going to datagram sockets (both UDP and Unix domain datagram sockets). Do I need to worry about `SIGPIPE`? I'm using `connect` on the socket, but preliminary testing (on Linux) showed that I just get `ECONNREFUSED` on send if there's nobody listening on the Unix domain socket. Not sure what happens with UDP.

I can wrap the whole thing in hacks to get rid of `SIGPIPE`, but if it's a non-issue I'd rather save the overhead and keep the code complexity down.

Comment: I'm going to give you a bad answer. I think I've seen it happen before when starting an application as the Linux system was booting. I can't say if it was definitely a datagram socket that was the underlying issue, but as far as I know we didn't use any TCP sockets for that application. Just a test case for you to consider if it might apply to you.

Comment: I think I might just arrange things to use `sendto` rather than `write` so I can pass that flag that disables `SIGPIPE`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is in the specification for `send`:

> [EPIPE] The socket is shut down for writing, or the socket is connection-mode and is no longer connected. In the latter case, and if the socket is of type SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_SEQPACKET and the MSG_NOSIGNAL flag is not set, the SIGPIPE signal is generated to the calling thread.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html

Thus, no, writes to datagram sockets do not generate `SIGPIPE` or an `EPIPE` error.

Comment: Doesn't the text above actually say that you *could* get it in UDP if "the socket is shut down for writing" (whatever that means)?

Comment: @T.E.D.: Perhaps (if shutdown-for-write works on a datagram socket), but that's a condition that would not happen without programmer intent or error. It's not caused by the peer.

Answer (score 8):

The open group is one thing, and Apple is another.
It is definitely possible to get a SIGPIPE on **iOS** when writing to a dead UDP socket, as some of my crash logs revealed lately.
iOS tends to close UDP sockets while the app is in the background, writing to these sockets can pop a SIGPIPE.
From my crash log (courtesy of testflightapp):

> Exception Latest Victim   Occurrences
>   SIGPIPE
>   2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32df47ec _sigtramp + 48
>   3 instant talk 0x0005b10e -[IPRSNetDatagramSocket send:size:to:] (iprs_iphone_net.m:671)...

Don't recall this happening on Linux, Solaris or Windows - though I never tried to close a socket and then write to it.

Comment: Closing a socket then writing to it will not give `SIGPIPE` or `EPIPE`; it will give `EBADF`. iOS must be putting the socket into some special nonstandard mode to cause `SIGPIPE`. In any case my question was tagged POSIX because I was looking for the standard behavior, but your answer is informative too.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man 2 write` on my Debian box,

> EPIPE: fd is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is closed.  When this happens the writing process will also receive a SIGPIPE signal.   (Thus,  the  write
>               return value is seen only if the program catches, blocks or ignores this signal.)

It appears that it is possible to get SIGPIPE when writing to a socket, but it's not clear whether it can happen for UDP sockets specifically.

Comment: The man page for `send` is somewhat more specific, but it's not as clear as what POSIX says about `send`..

Comment: Indeed, @R... I upvoted and your answer seconds after you posted it. I just meant to get the ball rolling with my post.